# Баг SVG - анимации в Firefox

Tags: html, css, svg

Такой вопрос: есть анимированная галочка SVG, при открытии файла (index) в Firefox анимация отсутствует, но если обновить страницу, все срабатывает.
У гугла все работает как часы.

Как исправить данный баг?

Данный код нашел на просторах стака. Просто хочу разобраться что да как. Информации не нашел, возможно плохо искал.

```html
<svg id="svg1" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
 width="94" height="94" viewBox="0 0 47 47"  >
 <title>animation icon -OK-</title> 
       <circle fill="#4CAF50" cx="24" cy="24" r="21"/>
         <path class="path" fill= "none" stroke ="#CCFF90" stroke-width ="1.5" stroke-dasharray= "70.2" stroke-dashoffset="70.2" 
         d="M 34.6 14.6  L 21 28.2 L 15.4 22.6 L 12.6 25.4 L 21 33.8 L 37.4 17.4z">
         <animate id="p1" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="0.2s" values="70.2;0" dur="3s" repeatCount="1" fill="freeze" calcMode="paced" restart="whenNotActive"/> 
         <animate id="f1" attributeName="fill" begin = "p1.end" values="#4CAF50; #CCFF90"  dur="2s" fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive" /> 
 </path> 
</svg>
```

Спасибо за помощь :3

Comment: Специально открыл FF, запустил код - всё норм, как и в Хроме.

Comment: Подтверждаю нормальную рабочесть кода в странице index.html в мозилле.

Comment: Это моя галочка, сразу по коду узнал. Надо же, уже где-то в интернетах бродит.  ещё в 2016 году сделал её [для статьи рисование линии](http://svg-art.ru/?p=1253)